# Nginx configuration to have served both static files sites than a reverse proxy for a .net core app

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I installed **Nginx** on my **Ubuntu 20.04** machine and I'm trying to serve a couple of simple static file along with a **Asp.Net Core (MVC)** app using Nginx as a reverse proxy.

### What I would like to achieve:

- http://example.com -> /var/www/StaticSiteFolder1/index.html
- http://example.com/Site2 -> /var/www/StaticSiteFolder2/index.html
- http://example.com/Site3 -> /var/www/StaticSiteFolder3/index.html
- http://example.com/NetCoreApp -> get the netcore app running on http://localhost:5000

### What I have done so far:

- Configured all static sites with the following .conf file inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

  ```
   server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name myServer;
   root /var/www/;

           location / {
                   root /var/www/StaticSiteFolder1;
                   index index.html index.htm;
                   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }

           location /StaticSiteFolder2 {
                   index index.html index.htm;
                   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }

           location /StaticSiteFolder3 {
                   index index.html index.htm;
                   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }}
  ```
- Created another .conf file for the reverse proxy, in the same directory:

  ```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name myServer;
    root /var/www/;

    location /NetCoreApp {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version   1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $scheme;
    }}
  ```

If I keep only the first one the static sites are served correctly.
If I leave only the second one changing "*location /NetCoreApp*" with "*location* /" and putting *default_server* in front listen 80 I have my netcore app correctly working on http://example.com.
I feel that it shouldn't be something so difficult but it's driving me crazy right now!
Thanks!

Comment: You have to use `location /Site1 {`, since you wanna configure that `location` with whatever is between `{}`. You miss your `root` property in the other site locations. Your rules are for `myServer`, not for `example.com`. I think, that is the reason, why `default_server` works: If no `server`-rule works, it will use the `default_server` rule for that port. EDIT: Note that `www.example.com` and `example.com` are technically two totally diffrent domains, you have to either configure both, or redirect all `www.` to non-`www`

Comment: You have two `server` blocks for the **same server** which will not work. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I read the documentation given by @RichardSmith and changed the server names. In the first file (static websites) I set "*.example.com" and "example.com" as server_name. It correctly resolve the address and gives me the correct static website (for example "www.example.com/StaticSiteFolder2" gives me  "/var/www/StaticSiteFolder2/index.html").In the second file I left "location /" and wrote "example.com/NetCoreApp" as server name but I looks like the "/" char is not correctly interpreted. How can I map all request for "example.com/NetCoreApp" to my reverse proxy?

Comment: Looks like you don't understand the documentation at all. Use all of your locations within the only one `server` block. BTW, the shorthand syntax for `server_name example.com *.example.com;` is `server_name .example.com;`.